# Can java parallel stream handle dependent tasks in a single thread

Tags: java, parallelstream

Let's say we have tasks 1-8, and we have 2 threads. Tasks 1-4 are allocated to thread 1 while tasks 5-8 are allocated to thread 2. It is possible to assign an execution sequence, for example, finish task 1 before starting task 2, task 2 will execute based on the output of task 1 for the tasks in the threads?

Comment: Order of execution is not in your control in parallel streams

Comment: If each task has to complete before the next task can start, then the logic is [`sequential()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#sequential--), the exact opposite of [`parallel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#parallel--), so why are you trying to use parallel streams? But yeah, sure, you can do `list.stream().parallel().forEachOrdered(...)`. I mean, it's dumb to ask for `parallel()`, just to turn around and ask for *ordered* execution, but whatever...

Comment: You have no control over parallel stream execution order or input partitioning.  If you need to control this you'll have to do your own coordination and use explicit threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.  Java stream parallelism functions in a very specific way which gives it complete control, in particular requiring that it can decide how operations are executed and in what order.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to use a countdown latch or similar to enforce it, though?

Comment: Probably not.  How Java streams break up the input, or if they even break up the input _at all_, is chosen by the implementation.  You can't guarantee that there will be two different tasks waiting for the latch at all.